# Alfresco trailing dot in folder name

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

In Alfresco 6.1 enterprise and 6.2 community edition, trailing dot in folder name gives error.

**Step to replicate:** Try to create any folder with a trailing dot (.). Manually or using REST call. I raised it on [Alfresco hub](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/trailing-dot-in-folder-name-gives-error-and-fails-the-rest-api/m-p/303879#M22504) too.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Or anyone knows about any open defect on the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about the "cm:name" property?
If so, this is per specification.

https://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/tasks/library-create-folder.html

Comment: Perfect. This is the piece of information I was looking for.